# how to handle webhook validation requests with MSgraph?

Tags: python, django, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to register my web app  in Microsoft azure ,to get notification about users one-drive change . to do so I need to register my app for getting notification.

I've been following these instructions:[Create subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/webhook-receiver-validation-request?view=odsp-graph-online#example-validation-request)

and here [Handling webhook validation requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0)

but I need some help with the validation of the webhook.
When a new subscription is created, OneDrive will POST a request to the registered URL(my web app or maybe I'll use azure function) in the following format:

```
POST https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/your/webhook/service?validationtoken={randomString}

Content-Length: 0
```

For the subscription to be created successfully, my service must respond to this request by returning the value of the validationtoken query string parameter as a plain-text response.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain

{randomString}
```

I'm using django , how do I make response in python like they asked?

this is how I send the first post request

```
def create_subscription(token):
  payload = {
    "changeType": "updated",
    "notificationUrl": notification_url,
    "resource": "/me/drive/root",
    "expirationDateTime": "2030-01-01T11:23:00.000Z",
    "clientState": "client-specific string"
  }

  headers = {
    "Authorization": token['access_token'],
    "Host": "graph.microsoft.com",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }

  response = requests.post("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions".format(graph_url),
                           data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

this is how I make the response for the POST request of Microsoft

```
def validate_subscription(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
      url = request.get_full_path()
      parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
      validation_string = parsed.query['validationtoken']

      headers = {
        "Host": "graph.microsoft.com",
        "Content-Type": "text/plain"
      }
      r = requests.post("{0}/subscriptions".format(graph_url),
                           data=validation_string, headers=headers)
      if (r.status_code == 200):
        return HttpResponse("Subscription suceeded")
```

we keep getting error that says 'validation error'

thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be sending a `POST` request back to Graph, you should be responding to *Graph's* request with the token it passed in:

1. You create a subscription
2. Graph issues a `POST` to your notification endpoint with a validation token.
3. Your notification endpoint responds to that `POST` with:

   ```
   def validate_subscription(request):
       if request.method == 'POST':
           url = request.get_full_path()
           parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
           validation_string = parsed.query['validationtoken']
           return HttpResponse(validation_string, content_type="text/plain")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

so what I did was to to use a capital 'v' for 'validationtoken' so the request should look like this :

```
def validate_subscription(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
  url = request.get_full_path()
  parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
  validation_string = parsed.query['Validationtoken']

  headers = {
    "Host": "graph.microsoft.com",
    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
  }
  r = requests.post("{0}/subscriptions".format(graph_url),
                       data=validation_string, headers=headers)
  if (r.status_code == 200):
    return HttpResponse("Subscription suceeded")
```